# Sum of exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-distribution, cauchy-product

Are there any ways to transform the product in 
 $$y=\left(\sum_ {k=1}^N a_k \exp\left(it \mu_k-\frac{\sigma^2_k t^2}{2}\right)\right) \times \left(\sum_ {k=1}^M b_k \exp\left(it \nu_k-\frac{\Sigma^2_k t^2}{2}\right)\right) $$
such that there results an equation in the form
$$y=A \exp\left(itB -\frac{C^2 t^2}{2}\right).$$

Thereby, $a_k$, $\sigma_k$ $\mu_k$ $b_k$ $\nu_k$ $\Sigma_k$ are real parameters.

The objective is to find $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that the above two equations are equal.

All I know is about Cauchy products but it seems that I cannot do a lot with it. 
If you have any suggestions, I would be grateful.

Comment: There are way way way too many variables to find a closed form of your product.

Comment: I assume that these sums are finite. In that case you do not need any Cauchy product. You can just change the second index from $k$ to $l$ and write all terms under a double-sum. Afterwards you can play around with the exponential terms. But, I doubt that will get you any further.

Answer (score 1):

As Tobias says, it depends on your constants.

$$\begin{array}
.y &= \left(\sum_ {k=1}^N a_k \exp\left(it \mu_k-\frac{\sigma^2_k t^2}{2}\right)\right) \times \left(\sum_ {l=1}^M b_l \exp\left(it \nu_l-\frac{\Sigma^2_l t^2}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_ {k=1}^N \sum_ {l=1}^M a_kb_l \exp\left(it \mu_k-\frac{\sigma^2_k t^2}{2}\right) \exp\left(it \nu_l-\frac{\Sigma^2_l t^2}{2}\right)\\
&=\sum_ {k=1}^N \sum_ {l=1}^M a_kb_l \exp\left(it(\mu_k+\nu_l)-\frac{(\sigma^2_k + \Sigma^2_l) t^2}{2}\right)\\
\end{array} $$

Unless all but one of your $a_kb_l$s is zero, or if your $\mu_k$s, $\nu_l$s, $\sigma_k$s, and $\Sigma_l$s are all constant, or something similar, you won't be able to combine all of your exponentials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, the only variable is $t$ .